# How do we validate an element is not displayed even when it is present in the DOM using Cypress

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I am trying to validate whether an `element` is not visible. I tried using **`element.should("not.exist")`** but it fails as the `element` is present in the `DOM`.

Is there a way we can validate that an element is not displayed?

Comment: You previously wrote "`.should('not.be.visible')` doesn't work for Cypress 6.6.0". What makes you think that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this assertion like so:

```
cy.get('<element-selector-here>').should('not.be.visible');
```

Also, you can assert the `element` exist & it's not visible like so:

```
cy.get('<element-selector-here>').should('exist').and('not.be.visible');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery and Chai assertion to check that the element is not visible.

```
cy.get('<element-selector-here>').then(($el) => {
  expect($el.is(':visible').to.be.false)
})
```

Comment: You have a bracket out of place.